# Photon frequency (energy) contradiction

Tags: general-relativity, energy, photons, frequency

I'm interested in full general relativity, not just special relativity.

In natural units a photons frequency (energy) from the point of view of an observer moving with 4-velocity $u^\mu$ is given by,

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
E = \nu = -p^\mu u_\mu
\end{equation}

The 4-momentum of a massless particle is given by,

\begin{align}
p^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} = \frac{dt}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\mu}{dt} = \nu n^\mu
\end{align}

where again $\nu =dt/d\lambda$ is the photon frequency and $n^\mu = dx^\mu/dt$ its 4-velocity
(note: $n^0 = dx^0/dt = dt/dt = 1$ in my coordinates).

I choose the eulerian observer to measure the photons frequency,

\begin{align}
u^\mu = \frac{1}{\alpha}(1,-\beta^k),\qquad u_\mu = (-\alpha,\vec0)
\end{align}

Thus, the frequency observed by the eulerian observer must be,

\begin{align}
\nu = -p^\mu u_\mu = -\nu\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\n^k \end{array}\right) (-\alpha,\vec0)
= \nu\alpha
\end{align}

This is obviously a contradiction. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Furthermore, I can't find any explanation to where equation (1) comes from. Can anyone explain to me why this equation gives the energy of a particle with 4-momentum $p^\mu$ from the point of view of an observer moving with 4-velocity $u^\mu$?

Comment: The frequency changes in the reference of a moving observer. It looks like Doppler effect. Why do you think that there is a contradiction?

Comment: @PetrPolovodov For the doppler effect I would need 2 observeres moving relative to each other. As far as i can tell there is only 1 observer present, the eulerian observer.  Who or what is the second observer supposed to be?

Comment: I just realized that if I decompose $n^\mu = u^\mu + v^\mu$, where $u^\mu v_\mu = 0$, everything works out just fine. So somewhere I might be misunderstanding $n^\mu$?

Comment: I am not the specialist on a topic and do not know what is eulerian observer. And, I do not understand the remark on two observers. On a practical point of view, the frequency of a photon is its energy. And while an observer moves it can measure the energy of that photon with a detector. So no other observer needed.

Comment: Use $p^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}$ (as mentioned in your previous post), which is the normalisation condition. Then eqn (1) implies $\alpha=\nu$ See section 4.2 of this article https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.603.9113&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @KP99 I can't find a previous post of mine where i used $p^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu}{dt}$. The definition in this post should be correct. The statement $\alpha=\nu$ makes no sense. This would mean that dependent on the spacetime curvature only one particular type of photon frequency is allowed.
I also don't see how your given reference is of any help.

Comment: Go through the link to pdf that I have mentioned in your previous post; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/673545/scaling-of-null-vectors . This contains all the necessary derivations. You will need a consistent formalism where your information on spatial hypersurface (defined by observer velocity u) can be used to parameterize information on null hypersurface (generated by photon momentum). See section 4.2 . Unless you read it my previous statement won't make any sense